# From PHP to XML and then X12 EDI conversion

Tags: php, edi

I have written PHP code to calculate shipping rates for Estes Carrier, now I need to make EDI file to sent to carrier company. I dont have EDI code knowledge. i studied about 204 motor carrier load tender , but didn't help me more. do i need to convert first my PHP code in to XML and then into x12 EDI format? how?

Answer (score 3):

To output data as an EDI, you need to format your data such that it
has this EDI structure:

> ISA - Interchange header - Contains general sender and receiver information
>   GS - Functional group header - Document type information
>   ST - Transaction set header - Indicates start of transaction set and transaction identifier
>   ...
>   ... Depending on your transaction set , there will be different segements between ST and SE.
>   ...
>   SE - Transaction set trailer - indicates end of transaction
>   GE - Functional group trailer
>   IEA - Interchange trailer

Segments contain multiple elements and elements contain pieces of data.

Here is a EDI 214 example in which segments are separated by `~` and elements are separated by `*`:

```
 ISA*00* *00* *08*9251750000 *08*1234567890 *030627*1304*U*00401*000001403*0*P*>~
 GS*QM*8019721193*1234567890*20030627*1304*1403*X*004010~
 ST*214*8101~
 B10*5896152*5896152*XX~
 N1*SH*BAW PLASTICS INCORPORATED~
 N3*CENTURY IBUSINES CTR*2148 CENTURY DRIVE~
 N4*JEFERSON HILS*PA*15025~
 G62*86*2050812~
 N1*CN*FINSH LINE~
 N3*308 NMITOEFER OAD*~
 N4*INDIANAPOLIS*IN*46235~
 G62*17*2050816~
 LX*1~
 AT7*D1*NS*2050815*132*LT~
 MS1*INDIANAPOLIS*IN*USA~
 MS2*CWCE*04937~
 Q7*DCAS*1~
 AT8*GL*41923~
 SE*18*48101~
 GE*1*1403~
 IEA*1*000001403~
```

You will need to follow the x12 standard to construct or parse EDI's.

Here is a list of standard EDI document types: http://www.edibasics.com/edi-resources/document-standards/ansi/

I just google around to find EDI specifications to understand how to lay out my data, for example, here is one for EDI 214:
http://ffportal.freightforce.com/technology/edi/EDI214.pdf

Answer (score 1):

most edi setups are like this:
- you produce a export file from your application. Eg xml, csv, fixed records, etc. (in edi this is called 'in-house file)
- an edi translator translates this to x12
- communication.
Receiving x12 is reversed: communication->translation->import
Focus upon good imports/exports in your application, not upon x12; that is what translators do.
There are good open source translators eg http://bots.sourceforge.net but there are more (google!). Some can only use xml as in-house format; if you prefer that you will have to write the export as xml.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to convert it into XML first.  That's a wasted step (IMHO).  You should be able to write code to go from DB -> EDI.

EDI is simply a text document that adheres to a standard.  The standards are published (not for free), but the person requiring the 204 should be able to provide you with an implementation guide (IG).  This IG will tell you what you need to send, in the order you need to send it.  If an IG is not available, you can Google for a sample and start building off that.  When testing the document, the partner will tell you what you need to change.

There will be terminology like Segment, Element, delimiter, terminator.  When you create your text file, you will need to create segments (N1, REF) as an example.  You will also need to put the proper delimiters in the file, and use the correct segment terminator (usually agreed upon between partners, but common ones are: *,^,~.  The IG probably will not have the envelopes (ISA and GS segments). You will need to put those in the file and increment the control counters correctly.

My standard usual answer stil applies: I'm sure there is no $$ in the budget for a translator.  That would be the best approach rather than reinventing the wheel with PHP code.  Translators have built in syntax checking, drag and drop mapping, data modeling.  Takes some of the learning curve out.